# File to access for CPU load average on AIX

Tags: aix, cpu, load-average

Is there a file with the load average in it on AIX? I'm looking for something like Linux's `/proc/loadavg`.

Comment: I suspect you have to get it from `/dev/kmem`, like you did on all systems before `/proc` was created.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know AIX firsthand but that's probably the case. AIX has a `/proc` directory, but it only contains process information (`/proc/<PID>` directories somewhat like Linux — closer to Solaris's), not also files about general system information. AIX's `ps` runs with elevated privileges.

Comment: I didn't find anything in /dev/Kmem, is there another file where I can access average CPU load?